# How to return if Google Calendar Time or Calendar Event is Busy?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to determine if a calendar has availability during a specific time. Specifically, when a calendar event is manually created, there's a checkbox for **busy** or **free**:

[image: Image of Setting]

I would like to test if the calendar is free or not. I assumed this would have been a property in the calendar itself, but I do not see one in the [google calendar classes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar). (I was looking for some property along the lines of 'isBusy').

My next step would be to test if there are events at the requested time, and if there are, I again don't see a method to test if an event's setting is busy or not. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's what I have:

```
function getAvailability(startTime,EndTime){
  var myCalendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

  //sample date to test availability 
  var aDate = new Date(2020,3,19);
  var dayEvents = myCalendar.getEventsForDay(aDate);

  //specific event captured:
  var myEvent = dayEvents[0];
  Logger.log(myEvent.getDescription());
 //here is where I don't know what to do. 
 //How can I return if during this event's time if calendar is free?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the FreeBusy object to check this detail.

This can be done by creating a query similar to:

```
    var check = {
 items: [{id: calendarId, busy: 'Active'}],
 timeMax: "2014-09-09T21:00:31-00:00",
 timeMin: "2014-09-09T17:00:31-00:00"
};
```

and using the query:

```
var response = Calendar.Freebusy.query(check);
```

to get the details you have asked to check.

API Documentation for FreeBusy can be found here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy

Comment: thanks for answer. If you want to see my next headache... feel free: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218825/cannot-get-googles-try-this-api-to-work-for-freebusy