# Cannot get Google's TRY THIS API To work For FREEBUSY

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191652/how-to-return-if-google-calendar-time-or-calendar-event-is-busy/) a couple days ago, and I appreciate (and accepted) the answer. Unfortunately, like most issues, it just let to another question.

### My Question

why can't I get this "[TRY THIS API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)" to work for me?

```
{
  "calendarExpansionMax": 0,
  "groupExpansionMax": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.indian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles"

    }
  ],
  "timeMax": "2020-05-09T16:39:57-08:00",
  "timeMin": "2020-05-05T13:39:57-08:00",
  "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `ID` I'm asking for I've tried the below syntax to test on an [indian calendar here](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.indian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com).

- `ZW4uaW5kaWFuI2hvbGlkYXlAZ3JvdXAudi5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29`
- `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.indian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles`

I've also tried a couple integers as the limit
I've clicked the "ok" to allow it run the API so it confirms my identity on. But I keep getting this "reason":"notfound".

What am I doing wrong?

[Click here to see image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS77N.png)

Sorry, I know the answer to this is probably so obvious. I feel various tutorial videos/websites that have anything to do with API's are always a rabbit hole of directing viewers to go find out a bunch of other information not covered in the tutorial's website (in the case of my previous question, the accepted answer did this, but this is a help board so I would expect that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The ID you are using is **not** your actual calendar id, that is why it is not working.

Follow these steps to find your calendar ID:

1. go to your [Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar).
2. Navigate to your subscribed/available Google calendars list.
3. On the right of these you will find three vertical dots (see image), click those and select **Settings and sharing**.

[image]

4. Go to the bottom of the new page that will open and under **Integrate Calendar** copy the value of the first item that will be **Calendar ID**.

Then just replace the ID you have for the actual one.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: yep thanks so much. I was overthinking it. All i needed to put was my EMAIL instead of that long HTTP or ID. Thanks a lot.  Answer accepted and appreciated.